# Index size on VARCHAR column

Tags: mysql, sql, unicode

In trying to index a `VARCHAR(256)` fields I get the following error:

> MySQL said: Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.

It works using `VARCHAR(255)` but I'm curious why varchar translates to what seems like 3 reserved bytes for each 'char' in a field, if it's using variable width encoding, does it just assume 'worst case' for ever letter, so three bytes if `utf-8`?

Additionally, if I'm only using English, would the best way to get larger than 255 size to use `ascii` encoding on the column instead?

Comment: The character length is transformed to bytes for this calculation.

Comment: That's a constraint in older versions of MySQL but has been remedied in newer ones. Which MySQL are you using? Is 5.7 or 8.0 an option?

Comment: Are you using any collation?

Comment: 256 is quite short see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=d86e9d0bbf344da503b0ffa9fb1a3c87  but why do you want to index this in that size and maybe a FULLTEXT INDEX would be better

Comment: @tadman I'm currently using 5.7.

Comment: @nbk its an index on a filepath where we have unique filepaths.

Comment: @nbk Full text indexes are an entirely different thing.

Comment: 5.7 should be fine with `VARCHAR(255)`, but only just barely in `utf8` mode, not `utf8mb4`. 8.0 allows for much more generous limits since it has better support for `utf8mb4` (4 bytes per character).

Comment: Note you need to use `utf8mb4` if you want to support all of Unicode, including emoji: 

Comment: @tadman sure but for this there are filepaths in the 'asci' character range.

Comment: You could drop down to `latin1` if that'd help, as then you can have `VARCHAR(767)` without hitting the limit, but MySQL 8.0 is really the answer here where that limit's been bumped to 3072 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `CHARACTER SET` has a maximum length, in bytes.  For `latin1` and `ascii`, it is 1.  That each character takes one byte.

For `utf8` it may take 3 bytes, hence the factor of 3.  3*255+2 = 767.  The "2" is for the length.

`utf8mb4` covers all of the currently defined Unicode characters, and takes up to 4 bytes per character.

I say "up to" because English takes only 1 byte per char; European languages take 1 or 2 bytes.  Chinese and Emojis take 3 or 4.

The implementation of indexing needs to reserve space for the largest possible number of *bytes* for the column.  And there is (was) a limit of 767.  Newer versions raised the limit to 3072.

Meanwhile, do not arbitrarily use `VARCHAR(256)` or even `VARCHAR(255)`, pick some reasonable limit.